# Text nested in View, how to make view as size of content?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

For example I have following code:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Text>
    Hello, World!
  </Text>
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1
  }
});
```

This code actually makes my text underlined. But I have some problem related this one. Because I used `borderBottomWidth` to make my text underlined, all the width of `View` (100% of device width) becomes underlined.

The question is How can I make my View follow the context of Text. What means be only underlined as width of Text context automatically, not using the width property of `View`? Or is it possible in my case?

Answer (score 0):

You should give the underline style to the `Text` component not to the`View`. Like this:

```
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
        Hello, World!
      </Text>
    </View>
  </View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    //what ever you want for view
  },
  textStyle: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    paddingBottom: 20,
  }
});
```

[image]

Comment: When I use borderBottomWidth property to Text component, my bottom border becomes too close to my text. I actually want to increase my margin between bottom of the text and the bottom border. What I have to do to achieve this?

Comment: You should add padding to `textStyle`. I updated my answer.

Comment: borderBottomWidth: 1 for textStyle does not work for me...Looks like it is some problems in RN itself.

Comment: Can you update your question with your code that I can help you better.

Comment: I think it does not work. Looks like it is an issue in RN. Share link of issue with you https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6833

Comment: This issue was closed long time ago and I tested it, it's working properly. I think this issue is fixed. What is your RN version?

Comment: I have React Native v0.48.2.

Comment: I updated my answer again. I think it solve your problem.

Comment: Still does not work for me :( But thanks a lot for help! Really appreciate this.

Comment: I wonder that it is not working yet. I tested it on RN 48 and its screen shot is as above.

Comment: Really works. But what about ios? I tested it on ios and it doen’t work

Comment: I tested on android.